# facebook c# sdk integration from codeplex

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, codeplex

I am using c# sdk facebook integration from codeplex and getting a strange error:

I have the following in my web.config and get an error that it does not recognize

Compile Error:

Warning 12 C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\car\Phase_2\tissot\tissot4\Default.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Unrecognized configuration section facebook. (C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\car\Phase_2\tissot\tissot4\web.config line 17) C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\car\Phase_2\tissot\tissot4\Default.aspx 1 1 tissot4

```
<facebookSettings
appSecret="################"
appId="$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" 
/>

<canvasSettings
canvasPageUrl=http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/
authorizeCancelUrl=http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined the [`configSections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256.aspx)?

Since [Configuration Section Tags not defined is a Microsoft Bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311091) which can be resolved by adding the configuration section tag after the  section like this

```
<configSections>
    <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>
    <section name="canvasSettings" type="Facebook.Web.CanvasConfigurationSettings"/>
  </configSections>

  <facebookSettings
        appSecret="your_api_secret" 
        appId="your_app_id" />
  <canvasSettings
    canvasPageUrl="http://apps.facebook.com/graphtoolkit/"
    authorizeCancelUrl="http://apps.facebook.com/graphtoolkit/home/cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation) the `canvasSettings` element should contain the following:

- `canvasPage`
- `authorizeCancelUrl`

You have `canvasPageUrl` where as you should be using `canvasPage`

From the article mentioned above:

> Now, right below that tag you should
>   see the “canvasSettings” settings
>   element. Change it as follows (again
>   use the Facebook screen to help you):
>
> - canvasPage – Canvas Page
> - authorizeCancelUrl – “http://www.facebook.com “(or any URL
>     you want it to go to when
>     Authorization fails)

Comment: @user - can you add your config sections etc from your web.config to your question?